# how t check if notifications are allowed with FCM without triggering a permission prompt

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps

I want to know if the user has allowed notifications on the current browser so I can show that state on the UI, but I don't want to trigger the request permission unless the user performs an action to enable notifications.
This is kind of a chicken egg problem because I don't have a reliable way to identify the current user browser.
I can store the FCM token on the firebase database and fetch it on the FE. But each token is unique for each browser and I can not compare it to anything, the only way I have to check if one of the existing tokens is for the current browser is to use the `getToken` method from firebase FCM and check the returned token is on the list of tokens, but that may trigger a request permission prompt and I don't want that unless the user asks for it.

One possible solution may involve storing a flag on local storage, but if the user clears it the UI will show notifications as disabled when the user is still subscribed to the FCM topic. I know the [Notification API has a property that indicates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification/permission) if the user has granted notification permissions but that may have happened and the token not retrieved for some random network error, so I can not rely on this solely. Also it only indicates if the user has granted permissions, but on my application logic notifications may be disabled (because user choice) and that does not revokes the permissions.

Things are also not nice if user wants to disable notifications: in order to delete the token from the database, I need the current browser token, and the only reliable way to know the current browser token is to ask it with getToken which may trigger a request permission if the user has disabled notifications and I will never get the actual token and I need it to remove it from the database

Are there any guidelines about how to deal with this? The FCM docs are quite sparse

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution that I'm not sure if it is super robust, but it's simple and probably to meet most cases.

First, check if the current browser has notifications allowed. If not, just show that value on the UI because the user will not get the notifications anyway even if they are subscribed on the backend side.

If notifications are already allowed you can safely run getToken (will not trigger permission request) and compare the value against the values on the user/profile database.

Because I'm using react here is an implementation on a hook:

```
  const areNotificationsAllowed =
    Notification && Notification.permission === "granted";

  useEffect(() => {
    // because we don't want to trigger a permission request
    if (!areNotificationsAllowed) return;
    // Notifications are allowed, we can safely run getToken to see if they are activated on this browser
    messaging.getToken({ vapidKey }).then((token?: string) => {
      if (!token) return setNotificationsEnabled(false);
      if (notificationsCfg[token]) setNotificationsEnabled(true);
    });
  }, [areNotificationsAllowed])
```